# discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 FORBIDDEN (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've recently created a bot which is only allowed to send messages and read message history. In my own servers, the bot seemed to work flawlessly, but a certain user tried using the bot on his own server and the error `discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 FORBIDDEN (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions` popped up.

```py
await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(io.BytesIO(meme), filename="meme.png"))
```

The line above is what's causing the error. I'm thinking that I need the 'Attach Files' permission, but for some reason it works without it on my testing servers.

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nemplayer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot/bot.py", line 78, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(io.BytesIO(meme), filename="meme.png"))
  File "/home/nemplayer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 806, in send
    content=content, tts=tts, embed=embed, nonce=nonce)
  File "/home/nemplayer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 218, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 FORBIDDEN (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Answer (score 26):

my issue was that the added role had higher priority than the bot's role (even with permissions) - so it was higher in the role list. just drag it higher and it should work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Whoa!  This actually works.  I don't know if this is documented anywhere, but even with the "Manage Roles" or "Administrator" permission, a given role cannot manage roles that are above itself.  I added a new role A, and then later added the bot to my server (which was auto-given its own role).  I wanted the bot to manage role A and add users to it.  But I was getting Missing Permissions, even if the bot had Administrator.  Dragging the bot's role ABOVE the role A to be managed in the server role list fixed it.

Comment: Go to server setting then into roles and drag it to the first in the roles list

Comment: This helped solve the issue, the order 100% matters.

Comment: I had a similar issue. The solution was NOT to add the bot to a different role. Keep it only in the generated role and add the channel permissions based on it.

I had channels that had specific permissions on it.

Answer (score 8):

As you said, [error code: 50013](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes#json-json-error-codes) means that you don't have permission to perform that action.

`ATTACH_FILES` is not the only [permission](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions) you must have, you may also need `SEND_MESSAGES` and `VIEW_CHANNEL` as they are ["Implicit Permissions"](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions#implicit-permissions), check if you have them too.

Comment: I'm mostly confused on how my bot works on my Discord Server with only Send Message and Read Message History permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced these kinds of issues while I was working on my project. to solve this issue, simply navigate to the **Discord developer portal**, pick **OAuth2**, select the **URL Generator**, set the bot permissions to **Administrator**, copy the link, and select your practice server, now have an access to all functionalities while developing your own bot.[image: Discord Developer Portal]

Comment: FYI: while this sort of works, you still need to change the order of the role so it's above the other roles in the role list view for your server settings. all what you are describing is doing is auto making a role for the bot, you can actually set this later by creating a manual role and giving admin permission or whatever you need.  Put another way the role can not change a member to another role unless the bot role is above the role you are trying to change to.