# How can I add a role to a user with discord.py/my discord bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've made a little discord bot in python to run it on my server, but i don't want to have randoms in my server so i created this command.
When executed the "code" (can also seen as password), the user get the user role (from the visitor role)

My code:

```py
@client.command()                                                                   
async def test(ctx):                                                               
    user = ctx.message.author                                                       
    await user.add_roles(discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, id=...))
```

The error I get:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception:
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

What I tried so far:

- Give the bot all permissions
- Elevate the bot at highest hierarchy.

So, could anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you try to change `user = ctx.message.author` with `user = ctx.author`?

Comment: I've made this change, but it didn't affect to outcome

Comment: How about you split the get role and add_role

Comment: I've tried multiple options, but that didn't helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the error code at [The discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes#json-json-error-codes), Error Code 50013 Is `You lack permissions to perform that action` or the bot can't do the action you wanted it to do. [More Info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56822419/discord-errors-forbidden-403-forbidden-error-code-50013-missing-permissions).

> Note: There's probably something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question to this one, that had some answers, so I tweaked the code to figure something out, try this, it worked for me:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    user= ctx.message.author
    role = (discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, id=insert id here))
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send("Successfully assigned {}!".format(role.mention))

client.run('token for obvious reasons here')
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't helped as well. I get the same error message

Comment: Then maybe this part of the code isnt the problem, but some other string?