# I'm making a discord bot that gives roles upon a reaction. I keep on getting the missing permissions error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 855128466072272937:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == '✅':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Attending')
        elif payload.emoji.name == '❌ ':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Not Attending')
        else:
            pass

        if role is not None:
            member = payload.member
            if member is not None:
                print('almost there')
                await member.add_roles(role, reason=None, atomic=True)
                print('done')
```

This keeps on giving me the error "discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions". The bot currently has admin and I've tried removing it and re adding it to the server but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

I made a new function in the bot that works perfectly upon the event and it doesn't give me any errors.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content == "give me admin":
        member = message.author
        role = get(member.guild.roles, name='No')
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

No errors came up when I tried this and it gave me the role.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 FORBIDDEN (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56822419/discord-errors-forbidden-403-forbidden-error-code-50013-missing-permissions)

Comment: If @enzo's link doesn't answer your question, please include the traceback to better indicate which call is failing.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, it seems the bot is missing permissions. You should ensure it has the manage roles permission. Generally I just give my bots admin if it's in one of my own servers.

You should also ensure that the bot's role is above any roles it will be giving/removing otherwise it will not have permission to assign these roles.

Comment: I gave it admin and removed it and re added it to the server a few times in the past to see if that would solve the problem but it didn't. The bot currently has admin

Comment: Make sure the bot's role is above the role you are trying to give.

Comment: @Vegas updated the main answer to say this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to give the bot permission to manage roles or administrator.