# Can I make a discord.py bot with ads link block and give them blacklist role

Tags: discord.py

From my topic I wanna make a bot and it feature is can remove ads link and give blacklist role to people who send the link

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code should work for you. If you want to add more words / sentences to the blacklist, you simply have to enter them in the list. You also have to enter the ID of the blacklist role.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, msg):
    Blacklist= ["https://discord.gg/", ".com"]
    for black in Blacklist:
        if black .lower() in msg.content.lower():
            await msg.delete()
            role = get(msg.guild.roles, id=role_id)
            await msg.author.add_roles(role)
            await msg.channel.send(f"You just Used an Blacklisted Word.")
```

Comment: I got this problem in vscode : "get" is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)

and got this in pycharm :
Unresolved reference 'get', 
Parameter 'self' value is not used, 
Variable in function should be lowercase

Comment: you need to install and import Discord.utils first  https://pypi.org/project/DiscordUtils/

Comment: Also if you dont use Cogs, you need to delete the self and replace the @commands.Cog.listener() with @client.event

Comment: I still got : "get" is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)

Comment: you also need to do "from discord.utils import get"

Comment: I got this : discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions but I already give it administrator permission

Comment: Try Reading This, maybe this can Help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56822419/discord-errors-forbidden-403-forbidden-error-code-50013-missing-permissions

Comment: uh...I have another problem
Can I make exception to some room to send a link

Comment: yes, you need to put "channelexception  = [id, id, id]" on Top and then "if not msg.channel.id in channelexception:". but instead of id you need to write down the ids from the channels

Comment: and can I make exception to some role?

Comment: DiscordUtils has nothing to do with discord.utils, discord.utils is provided by discord.py and DiscordUtils is a 3rd party package